# failed to change the state value in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, recompose

I am using react-redux to update the state value.In my code I am using google map component and I want to display the location name retrieved from geocoder in a 'infowindow' of google map.

```
import React from 'react';
import { compose, withProps,withHandlers,lifecycle } from "recompose"
import { withScriptjs, withGoogleMap, GoogleMap, Marker,InfoWindow } from "react-google-maps"
import { MarkerClusterer } from 'react-google-maps/lib/components/addons/MarkerClusterer';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class DemoApp extends React.Component {
    render() {
        var areaName,locName;
        const MyMapComponent = compose(
            withProps({
                googleMapURL: ('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places&key=AIzaSyAoaDS6fIKlYvEHeTaakCxXqp-UwnggoEg'),
                loadingElement: (<div style={{ height: '100%' }} />),
                containerElement: (<div style={{ height: '400px' }} />),
                mapElement: (<div style={{ height: '100%' }} />)
            }),
            withScriptjs,
            withGoogleMap,
            lifecycle({
                componentWillMount() {

                    let geocoder = new window.google.maps.Geocoder();
                    geocoder.geocode( { 'latLng': {lat:this.props.newMap.lat,lng:this.props.newMap.lng}}, function(results, status) {
                        if (status == 'OK') {
                            console.log('here result of geocoder', results);
                            if (results[0]) {
                                let adrs_comp = results[0].address_components;
                                for(let  i = 0; i < adrs_comp.length; i++) {
                                    if(adrs_comp[i].types[0] === "locality" ) {
                                        locName = adrs_comp[i].long_name;
                                        console.log("loc name");
                                        console.log(locName);
                                        console.log("loc name");
                                    }
                                    if(adrs_comp[i].types[0] === "administrative_area_level_1" ) {
                                        areaName = adrs_comp[i].long_name;
                                        console.log("area name");
                                        console.log(areaName);
                                        console.log("area name");
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            console.log('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
                        }
                    });
                }
            })
        )(props =>
            <GoogleMap
                zoom={this.props.selectedMap.zoom}
                center={{lat:this.props.selectedMap.lat, lng:this.props.selectedMap.lng}}
            >
             <Marker
          position={{lat:this.props.selectedMap.lat, lng:this.props.selectedMap.lng }} >
          <InfoWindow>
            <p>{locName}</p>

          </InfoWindow>
          </Marker>
            </GoogleMap>
        );

        return(
            <MyMapComponent  newMap={this.props.selectedMap} />
        );
    }
}
const mapStateProps=(state)=> {
    return {
        selectedMap:state.mapReducer
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateProps)(DemoApp);
```

In the above code everything works perfectly except the displaying of locname inside of infowindow of google map component.After a lot of search I understand that the only way to change the locname is to store it in a state.I am using react-redux to change the state value.When i connect the 'demoApp' component with redux store I can only dispatch actions inside of it,MyMapComponent will only accept props values from it's parent.How can I dispatch actions inside  when the geocoder in MyMapComponent receives the value for the locname ?the other solution is to write this MyMapComponent into a seperate file so that i can connect with the store.But when I write the MyMapComponent into a seperate file and import it into the above code it shows following error

```
Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of from render
```

Comment: I would try to extract this inlined component passed to `compose`

Comment: thanks bro..........

Comment: can you please post the code when you get the output?